# Reversing a string and printing it in IA32 assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, att, reversing

So basically I'm trying to read a string, increase a counter (in this case, %edx) until I read a \n, and then, going backwards to print it reversed.

This is my code:

```
.section .data
cadsal: 
    .asciz "Por favor ingrese su cadena:\n"

leer:
    .asciz "%s"

salidafinal:
    .asciz "La cadena introducida, invertida es:\n"

imp:
    .asciz "%c\n"
```

.section .bss
    .comm cadena,50,1

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:

```
leal cadsal, %eax
pushl %eax
call printf
addl $4, %esp

leal cadena, %eax
pushl %eax
leal leer, %eax
pushl %eax  
call scanf
addl $8, %esp

xorl %edx, %edx
```

Contar:

```
movb cadena(%edx), %al
incl %edx
cmpb $0, %al
jne Contar

leal salidafinal, %ecx
pushl %ecx
call printf
addl $4, %esp

addl $-2, %edx
```

Invertir:

```
movb cadena(%edx), %al
pushl %eax
leal imp, %ebx
pushl %ebx
call printf
addl $8, %esp

decl %edx
cmpl $0, %edx
jge Invertir

movl $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

I'm using the command -nostartfiles when compiling. It works, but when I run it, segmentation fault appears when entering in "Invertir". I need help to detect what's wrong in this code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is `cmpb '\n', %al` which is missing the `$` sign required in at&t syntax to make it an immediate. As it is, `'\n'` is considered an address, and an invalid one at that. You should use `cmpb $'\n', %al`.

However `scanf` will not place `'\n'` into your buffer at all, because `%s` stops at whitespace. So you really want to be looking for a terminating zero byte instead, that is use `cmpb $0, %al`. Or, if you really need to read a whole line, use `fgets` instead.

If you fix that, you will run into the next problem which is that you have an `incl %edx` between your `cmp` and the `jne` which will change the flags so you will not be branching on the result of the comparison but the increment. Solution: swap the `cmp` and the `incl`.

Yet another problem is that some registers, including `%edx`, are caller-saved. As such they can be modified by called functions, and you do `call printf`. You should `push`/`pop` around both of those to preserve the value.

Even after all of that, you probably won't see any output until you print a final `\n` manually, due to buffering.

Note that if you intend to use C library, you should really not use `-nostartfiles`. Instead, you should use entry point `main` and assemble and link normally. Also, you should simply return from `main` (or at most `call exit`) and not use direct system call because that doesn't allow the C library to clean up properly. Incidentally, that would also flush the I/O buffers, so you would see the output even without an extra newline.

You should really learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. I'm sorry, I'm still an amateur in assembly. What do you exactly mean by: You should push/pop around both of those to preserve the value. What should I push?

Comment: `push %edx` before the `printf` business (including the argument setup) and `pop %edx` after the `add esp`.

Comment: Swapped first cmp and incl, "Contar" seems to be working fine now. I'm getting segmentation fault now in "Invertir".

Modified addl $-2 , %edx because contar finishes with %edx being one step forward from $0 (end of string).

Comment: Nevermind. Learned a bit how to use debugger. Changed a few things in my code. That pushl/pop thing saved my life. Thank you very much.